# カスタムクラスのダウンキャストの方法がわからない

Tags: c++

以下のように親クラス`Figure`の`vector`に子クラス`Triangle`、`Rectangle`を入れています。

その際に`Triangle`、`Rectangle`にあって`Figure`にはないメソッド`getArea()`をvectorの要素から呼び出しています。

それをすると`Figure`の`vector`に`getArea()`はないというエラーが出てしまいます。
それはもっともなのですが、ダウンキャストをしたいのですが、どうすればよいでしょうか？

### 見つけたダウンキャスト方法

ただこれだと`Rectangle`しかできない

```cpp
//エラー部分
cout << ((Rectangle *)&figure)->getArea() << endl;
```

### できそうな方法

これらは見つけましたが、実装方法がわかりません。

- dynamic_cast
- static_cast

```cpp
// どちらもエラーになる
cout << dynamic_cast<Rectangle *>(figure).getArea() << endl;
cout << static_cast<Rectangle *>(figure).getArea() << endl;
```

### プログラム全体

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Figure
{
protected:
    int width;
    int height;

public:
    Figure(int width, int height)
    {
        this->width = width;
        this->height = height;
    }
};
class Triangle : public Figure
{
public:
    Triangle(int width, int height) : Figure(width, height) {}
    int getArea()
    {
        return width * height / 2;
    }
};

class Rectangle : public Figure
{
public:
    Rectangle(int width, int height) : Figure(width, height) {}
    int getArea()
    {
        return width * height;
    }
};

class Line : public Figure
{
public:
    Line(int width, int height) : Figure(width, height) {}
    int getWidth(){
        return this->width;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Line line = Line(4, 2);
    cout << line.getWidth() << endl;

    vector<Figure> figureList{{
        Triangle(10, 3),
        Rectangle(10, 2),
    }};

    for (Figure& figure : figureList)
    {
        cout << figure.getArea() << endl; //エラー部分
    }
}
```

### 副題

- ダウンキャストはできてもしない方がいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ダウンキャストを使うなら(メモリ解放は省略)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Figure
{
protected:
    int width;
    int height;

public:
    Figure(int width, int height)
    {
        this->width = width;
        this->height = height;
    }
    virtual ~Figure() {}
};
class Triangle : public Figure
{
public:
    Triangle(int width, int height) : Figure(width, height) {}
    int getArea()
    {
        return width * height / 2;
    }
};

class Rectangle : public Figure
{
public:
    Rectangle(int width, int height) : Figure(width, height) {}
    int getArea()
    {
        return width * height;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<Figure*> figureList{ {
        new Triangle(10, 3),
        new Rectangle(10, 2),
    } };

    for (auto figure : figureList)
    {
        if (auto t = dynamic_cast<Triangle*>(figure))
            cout << t->getArea() << endl;
        else if (auto r = dynamic_cast<Rectangle*>(figure))
            cout << r->getArea() << endl;
    }
}
```

`dynamic_cast`は、指定したポインタ型にキャストできないと`nullptr`になるので、それを`if`文で判定して呼び分けることができます。
ただ、該当の型すべてについて`if`文を書かなければならないので面倒です。
なお、親のクラスに仮想関数がないと`dynamic_cast`が使えないので、`Figure`に仮想デストラクタを追加しています。

C++17が使えるなら、こんな方法もあります。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

using namespace std;

class Figure
{
protected:
    int width;
    int height;

public:
    Figure(int width, int height)
    {
        this->width = width;
        this->height = height;
    }
};
class Triangle : public Figure
{
public:
    Triangle(int width, int height) : Figure(width, height) {}
    int getArea()
    {
        return width * height / 2;
    }
};

class Rectangle : public Figure
{
public:
    Rectangle(int width, int height) : Figure(width, height) {}
    int getArea()
    {
        return width * height;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<variant<Triangle, Rectangle>> figureList{ {
        Triangle(10, 3),
        Rectangle(10, 2),
    } };

    for (auto& figure : figureList)
    {
        cout << visit([](auto& x) { return x.getArea(); }, figure) << endl;
    }
}
```

こちらも、`variant`の後に該当の型をすべて並べないといけないので面倒です。

Comment: `variant`は知らなかったです。綺麗に書けますが、確かにクラスを並べないといけないのはめんどくさいですね。
`dynamic_cast`はなぜ親クラスに仮想関数がないとできないのでしょうか?

Comment: `dynamic_cast`はその内部でオブジェクトの実行時型情報(RTTI; RunTime Type Information)をチェックしますが、このRTTIはオーバーヘッドとなるため仮想関数/仮想デストラクタをもつクラスでしか利用されません。

Comment: FYI: `std::variant`での格納型リスト明示を嫌うなら、[`std::any`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/any/any.html)を使うという手もあります。ただし利用側コードはより複雑になりますし、あくまでも手段の一つとして。

Answer (score 1):

純粋仮想関数を使うことをお勧めします。純粋仮想関数は関数は定義しないものの、派生クラスにはメンバー関数が存在することを保証します。

```
class Figure {
protected:
    int width;
    int height;
public:
    Figure(int width, int height){
        this->width = width;
        this->height = height;
    }
    virtual int getArea() = 0;
};
class Triangle : public Figure {
public:
    Triangle(int width, int height) : Figure(width, height) {}
    int getArea() override
    {
        return width * height / 2;
    }
};

class Rectangle : public Figure{
public:
    Rectangle(int width, int height) : Figure(width, height){}
    int getArea() override
    {
        return width * height;
    }
};
```

こうなっていれば、 `Figure::getArea()` はそのまま呼び出すことができます。

```
for(Figure figure: figureList){
    cout << figure.getArea() << endl;
}
```

なお、 この記述では `figureList` の各要素が `figure` へコピーが発生します。 `Figure&` とすることをお勧めします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。今回の例では確かに純粋仮想関数がぴったりですね。しかしある子クラスがgetArea()を必要としない場合に、純粋仮想関数を親クラスに設定したくないんですよね。

Comment: 純粋仮想関数を使いたくない理由をわかりやすくするために`Lineクラス`を追加しました。

Comment: 確かにカスタムクラスのforeachはポインタを使った方がいいですね。ありがとうございます。気づきませんでした。元コードに反映させていただきました

Answer (score 1):

これは直接的な回答ではありませんが、C++ダウンキャストに関する根本的な誤解があるようにも見えます。

> 見つけたダウンキャスト方法
> ただこれだと`Rectangle`しかできない
>
> ```
> //エラー部分
> cout << ((Rectangle *)&figure)->getArea() << endl;
> ```

ダウンキャスト(Downcast)は、基底クラス型(`Figure`)から派生クラス型(`Triangle`や`Rectangle`)というクラス階層の下方向へと型変換(Type casting)を行います。あらゆる型変換において、**変換先の型の明示** は避けられません。

つまり`Rectangle`型へ変換したいならソースコード上で`Rectangle`型を明示する必要があります。`Triangle`型やその他の型へも対応させたいなら、それぞれの型名がソースコード上に現れるのは必然です。

他回答で提示されているC++仮想関数(virtual function)は、利用時に **実際のオブジェクト型をソースコード上に明示することなく** 派生クラスのメンバ関数を呼び出せるという言語機能です。通常のクラス設計においては、仮想関数の利用をおすすめします。

---

> コメント：別の例での説明なのですが、基底クラス(Base)、派生クラス(A, B, C, D, E)があって、D, Eにはprint()という関数があって、A, B, Cにはprint()がないとした時にこの場合にもprint()を仮想関数にすべきでしょうか?

「クラス設計意図による」としか回答できません。

クラス設計として「`print()`メンバ関数を持つことを表現」するインタフェース(`IPrintable`)を用意する案も考えられます。

```
struct Base { /*...*/ };
struct IPrintable {
  virtual void print() = 0;
};

struct A : Base { /*...*/ };
struct B : Base { /*...*/ };
struct C : Base { /*...*/ };
struct D : Base, IPrintable { /*...*/ };
struct E : Base, IPrintable { /*...*/ };
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。別の例での説明なのですが、基底クラス(Base)、派生クラス(A, B, C, D, E)があって、D, Eにはprint()という関数があって、A, B, Cにはprint()がないとした時にこの場合にもprint()を仮想関数にすべきでしょうか?

Answer (score 0):

### 2つの方法で出来ました

以下のようにmainを変更して、2つの方法でダウンキャストできました

### 問題点1

どちらの方法も`クラスの識別`をしていないので、なにをTriangle、Rectangleにすればいいのかがわからない

### 問題点2

クラスの識別ができればコード的には`安全`なのか?

```
int main()
{
    vector<Figure> figureList1{{
        Triangle(10, 3),
        Rectangle(10, 2),
    }};

    for (Figure& figure : figureList1)
    {
        cout << ((Rectangle *)&figure)->getArea() << endl;
    }

    vector<Figure*> figureList2{{ //ポインタにした
        new Triangle(10, 3),
        new Rectangle(10, 2),
    }};

    for (Figure* figure : figureList2)
    {
        // static_castでダウンキャスト
        cout << static_cast<Rectangle *>(figure)->getArea() << endl;
    }
}
```